# How can I execute multiple cron jobs at different timings using node-cron in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, scheduler, jobs, node-cron

How can I execute this with different timings? Please help on this. Thanks in Advance...

```
const Cron = require('node-cron');
const Cron2 = require('node-cron');

var TaskOne = Cron.schedule('*/10 * * * *', async() => {
     
    //first job implemented here and its working fine  
    function1();
 });
 
 var TaskTwo = Cron2.schedule('*/11 * * * *', async() => {
     
    // Second job implemented here....
    //Why this block is not getting executed??????????????????????? 
    function2();    
});
```

How can I execute this with different timings? TaskTwo is not getting executed. Debugger not goes into TaskTwo. Please help on this. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

if `node-cron`  is not the only prefrence for you then you can use https://github.com/agenda/agenda

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: mm agenda also needs an external storage though.. isn't there anything that's self contained?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to `require` the same package twice, so you should remove `Cron2` on the second line. Thus the line `var TaskTwo = Cron2.schedule('*/11 * * * *', async() => {`  should be changed to:

```
var TaskTwo = Cron.schedule('*/11 * * * *', async() => {
```

As for why the second schedule is not working, it might be because you didn't `start()` the schedule, as shown in https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron#start. So adding the code below at the end of your script might trigger both cron to run:

```
TaskOne.start();

TaskTwo.start();
```